# Save plotly figure interactively (html) whilst preserving LaTeX font

Tags: python, html, plotly, latex

I created a plotly figure using python and I am aware that one can save the interactive figure in html format by using:

`fig.write_html("name_of_figure.html")`

For the axis labels, as well as the title of the figure, I used LaTeX fonts like this:

`fig.update_layout(title=r'$\text{Some title}_2$')`

When I render it in my browser directly the LaTeX fonts are displayed correctly. However, when I save the figure in .html format, the title, as well as the axis labels, are not rendered using LaTeX fonts. I rather see the plain text like *$\text{Some title}_2$.*
What can I do to circumvent that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `include_mathjax = 'cdn'` parameter to `.write_html`.

And read [the documentation of write_html function](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/#full-parameter-documentation) carefully :)

> **include_mathjax**: bool or string (default False)
>
> Specifies how the MathJax.js library is included in the output html div string. **MathJax is required in order to display labels with LaTeX typesetting.**
>
> If False, no script tag referencing MathJax.js will be included in the output.
>
> If 'cdn', a script tag that references a MathJax CDN location will be included in the output.  HTML div strings generated with this option will be able to display
> LaTeX typesetting as long as internet access is available.
>
> If a string that ends in '.js', a script tag is included that
> references the specified path. This approach can be used to point the
> resulting HTML div string to an alternative CDN.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(x = [0,1,2], y = [0,1,4])
fig.update_layout(title=r'$\text{Some title}_2$')
fig.write_html("example_figure.html", include_mathjax = 'cdn')
```